# GAE: API error. An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Get()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We've been getting this very frequently lately, on various queries that have worked fine until recently. Here's the full traceback:

```
...
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~hebkhan/16.370010861782528881/models.py", line 2548, in search_tree
    contentItems = db.get(contentKeys)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1533, in get
    return get_async(keys, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 844, in get_result
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1482, in __get_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1234, in check_rpc_success
    rpc.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 578, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 133, in CheckSuccess
    raise self.exception
Error: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.Get().
```

I've seen similar issues being mentioned but nowhere was there any hint to the source of the problem.

I should also mention that this app is using python2.5 and we've yet to make the transition to python2.7. However, I don't think the could be related since the error comes from an RPC call that occurs in the Datastore.

Comment: Are you using M/S or H/R data store ?

Comment: H/R (High-Replication)